# undefined d3.scale in Typescript

Tags: d3.js, typescript

I'm new with Typescript (2 weeks), and I work on project to wrap the d3.js framework.
I'm encountered a problem with the usage of "d3.d.ts", namespace, export module, import.

My problem : When I try to use the d3.scale.linear(), I have the error in my browser console :

```
    TypeError: d3.scale is undefined
```

The code :

```
/// <reference path="../typings/d3.d.ts">;
"use strict";
var linear = d3.scale.linear();
console.log("linear resolv !")
```

My compiler option (I've no error on the compilation process, but perhaps it's interesting) :

```
{
    "files": [
        "src/twod3/workspace.ts",
        "src/twod3/component/basic.ts",
        "src/twod3/component/data.ts",
        "src/twod3/component/operation.ts",
        "src/main.ts"
    ],
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "target": "es2015",
        "module":"commonjs",
        "sourceMap":true
    }
}
```

I try different import strategy without success.

The d3.d.ts

```
declare namespace d3 {
...
    export module scale {
            ...
            export function linear(): Linear<number, number>;
            ...
     }
}
```

I don't understand the problem, thank you for your help.

Comment: Precision : <pre>d3.select(...)</pre> work fine

Comment: try `d3.scaleLinear`  instead `d3.scale.linear`of i guess you are using d3 version 4

Comment: That's work. Thank you.

Comment: d3.scaleLinear is missing of D3 Typings =/

Answer (score 35):

**Be careful of the version for d3.js**
In version 4.2.1 d3.scale.linear(); gives the following error.
TypeError: d3.scale.linear()  scale is undefined

**I fixed this error in version 4.2.1 by using d3.scaleLinear();**

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar kind of issue. I had to match the D3 version, that supported the in built methods for d3.
Either match the version of the D3.js, make sure you update your browser or match the in built methods for your current version.

My supported version for `d3.scale.ordinal` is '3.5.17', previously I was at the latest version.

Comment: So i am using the d3@3.5.17, now i also need the typing for the same version, but when there is no typings for the version 3.5.17, which version are you following?